# How to find the same number in sublists of list

Tags: list-manipulation, intersection

```
Intersection[Table[Table[Sqrt[p1]/r1,{r1,0.1,0.7,0.1}],{p1,0.5,5,0.5}]]
```

I am trying to find same numbers in the sublists. But Intersection is not working for this...

Comment: What if you use exact numbers (e.g. `1/10`) instead of inexact ones (e.g. `0.1`)?

Comment: Still not working...I think the curly bracket is creating problem.

Comment: You use the wrong syntax for [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection.html).  See the difference between `Intersection[{0, 1, 3}, {0, 10, 2}, {3, 0}]` (good) and `Intersection[{{0, 1, 3}, {0, 10, 2}, {3, 0}}]` (bad). In the second case (your case) it works if you write instead  `Apply[Intersection, {{0, 1, 3}, {0, 10, 2}, {3, 0}}]` or `Intersection @@ {{0, 1, 3}, {0, 10, 2}, {3, 0}}`. However in your case it seems the intersection is empty !

Comment: How will it give a sorted list of the elements common in any two sublists?

Comment: santosh, your last comment seems to ask a different question. Do you want elements common to *any two sublists*, or elements common to *all sublists*? I understood your original question to be the latter. Please clarify.

Comment: I also want elements common in any two sublists.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
Apply[
  Intersection[#, SameTest -> (EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] < 10^(-5) &)] &,
  Table[Table[Sqrt[p1]/r1, {r1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1}], {p1, 0.5, 5, 0.5}]
]

(* gives: {1.01015, 1.17851, 1.41421, 1.76777, 2.35702, 3.53553, 7.07107} *)
```

You can probably adjust the numerical tolerance (10^-5) as needed.

Comment: It gives first list {7.07107, 3.53553, 2.35702, 1.76777, 1.41421, 1.17851, 
  1.01015}. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're after something like this:

```
ReplaceList[myListofLists, {a : ___, {b : ___, x_, ___}, c : ___, {d : ___, x_, ___}, ___} :> 
    {{Length@{a} + 1, Length@{b} + 1}, {Length@{a} + Length@{c} + 2, Length@{d} + 1}, x}]

(*
{{{1, 1}, {4, 2}, 7.07107}, {{1, 2}, {4, 4}, 3.53553}, 
 {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, 2.35702}, {{2, 1}, {8, 2}, 10.}, 
 {{2, 2}, {8, 4}, 5.}, {{2, 3}, {8, 6}, 3.33333}}
*)
```

Gives list with elements of {{Position of first list, position in that list},{position of second list, position in that list},number}... the coordinates can be converted to the values of *p1* and *r1* by multiplication by chosen increment and addition of chosen initial values for the table iterators.

If all you care about are the actual values,

```
Union @@ Intersection @@@ Subsets[myListofLists, {2}]
```

will suffice.